# Github action doesn't show error despite non-zero python exit code

Tags: python-3.x, github-actions

I have a python script that exits with an error code inside a Github action, but the action still shows a success. I'd like for it to show an error when a non-zero exit code is thrown. Is there anything that should be changed in the script or workflow?

Python script:

```
import sys
import os
error_code = 256
print(f'error_code: {error_code}')
os._exit(error_code)
# have also tried sys.exit(error_code)
```

Github Workflow:

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Setup Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'

    - name: test
      run: python3 ./test_error_exit.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux based systems, process exit codes are the 8 least significant bits of the number returned.

This means returning 0-255 is valid, and after that it wraps around. (256 becoming 0, 257 becoming 1, etc.)

Please try again with an exit code like 5.

```
import sys
sys.exit(5)
```

Comment: It does work if I do like you propose. I was getting 256 back from os.system('gcloud ...') and passing that to sys.exit(). Now I will just call sys.exit(1).

Comment: Do you have a source for "there is no such exit code"? I don't think this really answers the question - for me, Python returns errorcode 9009, but Github Actions also thinks this was a successful run even though the documentation states anything non-zero is recognized as error... https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/setting-exit-codes-for-actions#about-exit-codes

Comment: On linux systems, and iirc POSIX systems in general, the exit code is the least significant 8 bits of the returned status.
https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid
Look for "WEXITSTATUS"

Comment: Since only the last 8 bits are considered the status, anything over 255 will get wrapped, meaning 256 will be exit code 0.